# I want to create a pop up box on a site i am working on, i like the pop up box facebook and linked in has, how do i create it?

Tags: php, popup

I want to create a POP up box on a site i am working on, i like the pop up box facebook and linked in have, how do i create it? is there a code or something?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you mean the thing at the bottom for facebook chat?

Answer (score 2):

[Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) - as mentioned above - will allow you to do this.

To expand a little further, pop up dialogs as you described are created using javascript.

The process you're most likely looking for is that you set up a link element, pointing to the content you would like to display in the dialog. Notice the `rel="facebox"` attribute - this is how we'll know to open this link in a popup.

```
<a href="remote.html" rel="facebox">text</a>
```

You then include the javascript plugin (and needed files, like the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) and plugin css files) to provide the popup function. This should be done in the `<head>` of your page.

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/facebox/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/facebox/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now you need to set the popup function to be applied to the link - the following should be applied in the `<head>` section after the above links, or in a separate file. This snippet tells all links with `rel="facebox"` to open in a popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
    });                        
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [JQuery](http://www.jquery.org) + a dialog plugin.

Here is one [example](http://www.developertutorials.com/blog/javascript/creating-facebook-like-popup-dialog-in-your-web-app-94/)

You also have the [JQuery Dialog implementation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox). It's very easy to use and provides a similar look and feel. It's a jQuery plugin with [more information](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/facebox) available at the jQuery plugins site if needed.